# Linear programming using MATLAB

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, matlab

I'm currently trying to solve a problem. According to some people I know it's a linear programming problem, however, I've not had the course just yet.

Situation:
At my warehouse we get different types of materials to craft the final product $r$. The production depends on how well you can manage the stock so that you won't run out of intermediate resources. I basically have to maximize crafting product $r$. In order to do so, I need to know how much I need to craft from each intermediate step. The final working code will provide me information on how much $gp$ and then $e$ I should craft.

To make one $r$, you need 150 $gp$ and 10 $e$.
So I formulated my steps as follows:

$$r = 150 gp + 10 e$$
$$10 gp = 20 s$$
$$e = 50 gp + 10 s$$

Obviously you cannot craft more than your stock allows you to, so I am upperbound by my stock. This stock is variable every cycle I need it, as the stock constantly changes.

$$s \leq 500000$$

$$gp \leq 11866$$

$$e \leq 1107$$

Also said stock cannot be negative as it is a real problem.

For visualization I've attached a [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrNkW.png)  to see what the relations are between each resource.

I've found a function in MATLAB that should be able to be able to solve my problem.

`[X,Z] = linprog(f,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)`

I know I need to set up an objective function to maximize/minimize over, and I need to replace the variables with $x_1 ... x_n$. However, I don't know how to tackle it right at the moment.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for linprog?

Comment: Yes I've read the documentation, however, I cannot formulate a suitable objective function f to use linprog.

Comment: There is a bit of problem. Your optimization is not linear here since you also have non-linear constraints

Comment: @MostafaAyaz do you know a way of optimizing this problem? I would love knowing which direction I should be looking to get a solution.

Comment: You can use the **fmincon**  MATLAB toolbox. I also suggest you to simplify the optimization problem as much as you can. For example, the objective function can be explicitly written as a function of $s$.

Comment: you can also take a look at [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/), and it is pretty easy to use.